# How to install pypy in google colaboratory, and use it?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pypy

I want to use pypy (or pypy3?) in colab, but there is no difference with the usual code. Can you help me, please?
[image: Two code differences]

```
!apt-get install pypy
!%%pypy
import time

for k in range(10):
  start=time.time()
  for i in range(1000):
    for j in range(100):
      for h in range(1000):
        dosmth="nothing"
  print(time.time()-start)
```

UPD: I made Fibonacci function, but there is no effect.

[image: Slow pypy]
UPD 2: Made cycle, but doesn't work so well.
[image: The cicle]

Comment: It looks like your benchmark code is too-artificial. It willbe fairly efficient in traditional Python, as the loops do not involve any real calculations, and the inner most code is basically a no-operation. Write a naive fibonacci or prime-number finding function and yu should see some difference for the better.

Comment: I made the Fibonacci function as you said, but there is no effect. Please see my edited question.

Comment: Can't answer your question, but just wanted to point out that your original code of empty loops should run much, much faster on PyPy, whereas Fibonacci is full of long numbers and so can't be faster on PyPy.  If the original code is not faster, then it's not using PyPy.  To know for sure: ``import __pypy__`` works on PyPy and not on CPython.

Comment: I edited it again, the cycle too works not so fast. Are there any mistakes?